# Is $B \cap L^2\big( (0,T) \times (0,1)\big)$ closed in $L^2\big( (0,T) \times (0,1)\big)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I need help proving that the set $B \cap L^2\big( (0,T) \times (0,1)\big)$ is a closed subset of $L^2\big( (0,T) \times (0,1)\big)$, where $B$ is defined as:

$$B=\Big\{x \in L^{\infty}\big(0,T;L^1(0,1)\big) \ : \|x(t)\|_{L^1(0,1)} \le 1 , \ \ \text{a.a in } \ (0,T) \Big\}   $$

Any suggestions or proofs would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C} $To attach a meaning to the intersection $C:=B\cap L^2\big((0,T)\times(0,1)\big)$ of the subset $B$ of the space $L^{\infty}\big(0,T;L^1(0,1)\big)$ with the space $L^2\big((0,T)\times(0,1)\big)$, we need to identify functions $(0,T)\times(0,1)\ni(t,s)\mapsto x(t,s)\in\C$ in $L^2\big((0,T)\times(0,1)\big)$ with functions $(0,T)\ni t\mapsto x_t\in L^{\infty}\big(0,T;L^1(0,1)\big)$, which we will do by the standard formula $x_t(s):=x(t,s)$.

Let $(x^{(n)})$ be a sequence in $C$ converging to some $x\in L^2\big((0,T)\times(0,1)\big)$ in $L^2\big((0,T)\times(0,1)\big)$:
\begin{equation}
    d_n:=\int_0^T dt\,\int_0^1 ds\, |x^{(n)}(t,s)-x(t,s)|^2\to0
\end{equation}
(as $n\to\infty$). We have to show that then $x\in B$, so that $x$ is actually in $C$.

Using the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\int_0^T dt\,\int_0^1 ds\, |x^{(n)}(t,s)-x(t,s)| \\ 
    &\le\sqrt{T\times1}\Big(\int_0^T dt\,\int_0^1 ds\, |x^{(n)}(t,s)-x(t,s)|^2\Big)^{1/2}
    =\sqrt T\sqrt{d_n}\to0. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
That is, $\int_0^T dt\, g^{(n)}(t)\to0$, where $g^{(n)}(t):=\|x^{(n)}_t-x_t\|_{L^1(0,1)}$. That is, the sequence $(g^{(n)})$ of nonnegative functions converges to $0$ in $L^1(0,T)$ and hence in measure over the interval $(0,T)$. So, passing to a subsequence, without loss of generality we may assume that the sequence $(g^{(n)})$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere on $(0,T)$. That is, $\|x^{(n)}_t-x_t\|_{L^1(0,1)}\to0$ for a.a. $t\in(0,T)$. Recall that for each $n$ we have $x^{(n)}\in C\subseteq B$, whence $\|x^{(n)}_t\|_{L^1(0,1)}\le1$ for a.a. $t\in(0,T)$. So,
\begin{equation}
    \|x_t\|_{L^1(0,1)}=\lim_n\|x^{(n)}_t\|_{L^1(0,1)}\le1
\end{equation}
for a.a. $t\in(0,T)$. Thus, $x\in B$. Thus, $x\in B$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the transition from convergence in measure of $(g^{n})$ to almost everywhere convergence is established by employing the Riesz-Fischer theorem?

Comment: @elmas : No, the Riesz–Fischer theorem is not used here. That the convergence in measure implies the almost everywhere convergence for a subsequence is a simple theorem, found I think in almost any textbook on measure theory -- see e.g. Theorem 2.30 on p. 61 of Folland, Real Analysis, Second Edition. (You can also find this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Properties). More immediately here, you can use Corollary 2.32 on p. 62 of Folland's book, stating that the convergence in $L^1$ implies the almost everywhere convergence for a subsequence.